# How to add parent div with form builder in symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

form created by form builder

```
<form name="post" method="post">
  <div id="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" id="post_title" name="post[title]" required="required" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea id="post_content" name="post[content]" required="required" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" id="post_postAdd" name="post[postAdd]" class="form-control btn-primary">Create</button>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="post__token" name="post[_token]" value="ab35508c9.6MnqGe6WDVVVtkdRga_Ahtt5kDssuXri3JBx4HcVdOw.gKCQYdugYSw2_x88wN2y6Z5P_mtJyxaqm95GhkRDP52qoYFjucJOGyTuIA" />
  </div>
</form>
```

i want this. How i create parent (div) elements one or more like below with form builder. Not in twig.

```
<div class="oneMore"> <!-- I need this element -->
    <div class="iWantToAddThis"> <!-- I need this element -->
      <div class="form-group">
        ...input...
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        ...input...
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

PostType.php. I created form like below.

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                ],
                'row_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-group'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('content',TextareaType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                ],
                'row_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-group'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('postAdd', SubmitType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control btn-primary'
                ]
            ]);
    }
```

_form.html.twig (I don't want to add anything in twig)

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

Comment: Look into [Form Themes](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html). You can customise how Symfony builds the input Types etc...

Comment: Thanks . But i wanted to solve in formbuilder. And i found a solution. i did with $builder->create